# Android App Development Image Location Question

Tags: java, android

I want to make sure that all models are in the same position.
However, the location changes for each model.
What should I do?

[Position set in xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XlA4.png)
[Emulator execution position (different for each type)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlJxx.png)

[img code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUMBK.png)

I don't know what to do

Comment: Have you tried running your app on a smartphone? Sometimes the layout of the emulator is slightly different from the layout on the smartphone.

Comment: Add code snippet instead of the image

Comment: For us to help we'd need the entire layout of that part of the screen, including it's parent and whatever is beneath it.  There's not enough info from just what you posted to tell anything.  But its likely that your bias values are off, and very likely that's not the right way to do this.